# How can i use the io.kubernetes official java client to do a rollout restart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there any Java api in the io.kubernetes/client-java that I could use to perform a rollout restart for a given deployment? Something similar to io.fabric8/kubernetes-client?

Comment: Please make use of the [extensive search functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkubernetes%5D+rollout+restart) during your stay here in the stack exchange network

Comment: My question did not have an answer in the stackoverflow community. I managed to answer my own question but I wasn't able to post the solution here because the question was closed in an unjustified manner. Thanks!